# Write All Filenames in Specific Folder to Pandas Dataframe Table Column

Tags: python, dataframe, import, directory, filenames

Let's say I have the following folder which contains .txt and .wav audio files.

[image]

I want to create a dataframe table that has each row of data as one of those .wav files.  It would look something like this as a sample output:

[image]

In total, there should be 460 rows of data, one for each .wav file.

How do I do this in Python code?  I've searched all around StackOverflow but can't find an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get a list of files and loop through them with a condition to check the extension.

```py
 import pandas as pd
 import os
 file_list = []
 for file in os.listdir('/path/to/dir'):
    if file.endswith('.wav'):
        file_list.append(file)
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Filename': file_list})
```

Once you have the file names, you can add them to your DataFrame in whatever way you like.